# modeling 5 ordinary differential equations and plotting the model to show the 5 equations

Tags: python, ode

hello I am newbie at python and coding for the most part and I have 5 ordinary differential equations.(non-linear) that I want to model and have them plot. I have the parameters that are given, my main issue has been setting the independent variables to be a function of z. As well as setting the 'S' parameters to be a function of time since they vary depending on the time of year.
edited CODE

I've been able to have the code run with set parameters. I now wonder how I could take these parameters and make them behave at different times. The parameters that are set on this code are for a specific amount of "days" during the year. They are not meant to be consistent throughout. How could I implement time to have them be dependent on it?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
from math import e

def func(z,t):
    xh, xf, y, m, n = z
    v1,v2,v3 = 0.05,0.06,0.07
    B1,B2,B3 = 0.1984,0.1593,0.04959
    d1,d2,d3 = 0.02272,0.02272,0.2
    o1,o2 = 0.25,0.75
    S1=S2=S3=0.005
    S4=S5=0.3
    p = 0
    u = 500
    k = 0.000075
    a = 0.4784
    r = 0.0165
    K = 8000
    i = 2
    H = e**(-m*k)
    g = ((xh+xf)**i)/((K**i)+((xh+xf)**i))
    R = o1-(o2*(xf/(xh+xf+.002)))
    P1 =(xh+xf)/(xh+y+xf+.002)
    P2 = 1-((m+n)/(a*(xh+y+xf+.002)))
    P3 = y/(xh+y+xf+.002)
    dxhdt = (u*g*H)-(B1*(m*(xh/(xh+y+xf+.002))))-((d1+S1)*xh)-((v1*(m+n))*xh)-(xh*R)
    dxfdt = (xh*R)-(B1*(m*(xf/(xh+y+xf+.002))))-((p+d2+S2)*xf)-(v2*(m+n)*xf)
    dydt = (B1*(m*P1))-((d3+S3)*y)-((v3*(m+n))*y)
    dmdt =(r*(m*P2))+(B2*(n*P3))-(B3*(m*P1))-(S4*m)
    dndt = (r*(n*P2))-(B2*(n*P3))+(B3*(m*P1))-(S5*n)
    return [dxhdt,dxfdt,dydt,dmdt,dndt]

z0=[13000,11000,0,0,0]
t = np.linspace(0,100,1000)
xx=odeint(func,z0,t)
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(t,xx[:,0],'b-',label = 'xh')
plt.plot(t,xx[:,1],'y-',label = 'xf')
plt.plot(t,xx[:,2],'g-',label = 'y')
plt.plot(t,xx[:,3],'r-',label = 'm')
plt.plot(t,xx[:,4],'m-',label = 'n')
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('POPULATION')
plt.xlabel('TIME')
plt.show()
```

I though about creating two different functions and looping the plot. How do you makes "days" of function of t? just declaring it is? I get error code "TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"

```
z0=[13000,11000,0,0,0]
t = np.linspace(0,91.25,1000)
xx=odeint(func,z0,t)
xy=odeint(func2,z0,t)
plt.figure(1)
for t in range(1,91.25):
    plt.plot(t,xx[:,0],'b-',label = '$x_h$')
    plt.plot(t,xx[:,1],'y-',label = '$x_f$')
    plt.plot(t,xx[:,2],'g-',label = 'y')
    plt.plot(t,xx[:,3],'r-',label = 'm')
    plt.plot(t,xx[:,4],'m-',label = 'n')
for t in range(91.25,182.50):
    plt.plot(t,xy[:,0],'b-',label = '$x_h$')
    plt.plot(t,xy[:,1],'y-',label = '$x_f$')
    plt.plot(t,xy[:,2],'g-',label = 'y')
    plt.plot(t,xy[:,3],'r-',label = 'm')
    plt.plot(t,xy[:,4],'m-',label = 'n')
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('POPULATION')
plt.xlabel('TIME')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please provide cut and paste of the code and not photos.

Comment: You get this error usually if the system diverges at some point of the integration interval. Check how the solution so far grows. Sometimes this error appears when the solution enters a region where the equation becomes very stiff, you could use a lower order solver or a fixed-step solver to get over this with reduced accuracy. To some extend odeint already does this, vary the order of the method, so as said, this is rarely the reason.

Comment: You can implement time dependent parameters in using the time variable `t`, for instance `para = 3 if 20*day < (t % year) < 60*day else 10`, where the constants `day` and `year` and similar have to be defined to be multiplicators to the unit of `t`.

Answer (score 0):

I get what you mean by an ODE, but please expand it so others that are not cognizant of mathematics can understand.

If you want these to be a function of z, then you must declare a function something() and assign the variables this function. This way, your values will change with respect to changes in z.

Also by convention, I don't recommend using this much of variable declarations. Abstract these as much as possible. As an alternative, you can declare similar variables in the same line, like

v1, v2, v3 = 0.5, 0.6, 0.7

etc. This will make it much more readable.

If you don't have any syntax error due to multiple assignments in the first line, I recommend change each of this to be a function of z. Divide your bigger function to smaller chunks, make each of this a different function. This way you can manipulate results directly and code will be much more readable.

Answer (score 0):

You prefer the state vector to be composed as

```
xh, xf, y, m, n
```

This interpretation of the state vector then needs to be applied everywhere, which means that you have to change the first line of the ODE function to

```
xh, xf, y, m, n = z
```

Also check that your fractions are implemented as they were in paper, esp. `P1` appears suspicious. But without the genesis of the equation I can not say that it is wrong as it is.

[image]